# Is it possible to know how many bits in integer type?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I want to use some integer type as a bit mask. I want to know for which `n` it's guaranteed that any number from 0 to `2^n-1` is avaliablle in this type. (Actually I'm going to use `uintmax_t`)

I know it's usually `8 * sizeof(uintmax_t)` (or probably `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uintmax_t)`), but I guess it isn't guaranteed.

So I want, to find this `n` other way.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't assume 8 bits in a byte, so `CHAR_BIT` is better.

Comment: why do you have concerns abuot `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uintmax_t)`?

Comment: The number of bits is guaranteed, for *every type*, to be `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT`. This includes potential padding.

Comment: @Xeo, not always all this bits are used in structs/classes. Seems not obvious why it's right for built-in integers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using the [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) in combination with `CHAR_BIT`

```
const std::size_t nBits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(some_integer_type);
```

This would also work for other built-int types, as well as user defined types.

Comment: I do understand why it's number of bits that used for storing this type, but not Why it's number of bits I can actually store here. For example in `bitset<1>` or `bool` I can store only 1 bit, while, size is at least 8 byte

Comment: @RiaD For a built-in type you can store as many bits as the number of bits in that type. How these bits are interpreted in terms of numerical values is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `cstdint` include](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

It provides cross-platform fixed-size `typedef`s for integer types and macro constants for its limits.

```
#include <cstdint>
std::int8_t Signed = 0;    // granted to 8bit size.
std::uint8_t Unsigned = 0; // granted to 8bit size.
Signed = INT8_MAX;        // store the max value for a signed 8bit value.
Unsigned = UINT8_MAX;      // store the max value for an unsigned 8bit value.
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be `1+log2((UINTMAX_MAX>>1)+1)`

It can also be derived by counting bits with repeated shifting.

Comment: what do you mean by (uintmax_t>>1) ?

Comment: Thanks, I just copied blindly the label suggested by OP. Perhaps we can all delete the comments now...